# Why FreeRASP is not working as intended in a Flutter app despite proper configuration as depicted in their website?

Tags: android, flutter, security, apk

We have developed a Flutter app and recently added FreeRASP, which is a Runtime App Self Protection library for Flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/freerasp). Below is the code.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:freerasp/talsec_app.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  ...
  runApp(MyApp(...));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({...})
      : super(key: key);
  ...
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() =>
      _MyAppState(...);
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  _MyAppState({...});

  ...

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initSecurityState();
  }

  Future<void> initSecurityState() async {
    TalsecConfig config = TalsecConfig(
      // For Android
      androidConfig: AndroidConfig(
        expectedPackageName: 'com.company.mypackage',
        expectedSigningCertificateHash: 'xxxxxxxx',
        supportedAlternativeStores: ["com.sec.android.app.samsungapps"],
      ),

      // Common email for Alerts and Reports
      watcherMail: 'xxx@xxx.com',
    );
    TalsecCallback callback = TalsecCallback(
      // For Android
      androidCallback: AndroidCallback(
        onRootDetected: () => exit(0),
        onEmulatorDetected: () => exit(0),
        onHookDetected: () => exit(0),
        onTamperDetected: () => exit(0),
        onDeviceBindingDetected: () => print('device binding'),
        onUntrustedInstallationDetected: () => print('untrusted install'),
      ),
      // Common for both platforms
      onDebuggerDetected: () => print('debugger'),
    );

    TalsecApp app = TalsecApp(
      config: config,
      callback: callback,
    );

    app.start();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(...);
  }
}
```

But when it is run on an emulator, it is not even detecting that, even though we have directed it to `exit(0)` in that case. On debugging, the execution of `app.start()` gives the following log. Please advise.

```
W/india.mobileap( 4242): Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/internal/os/PowerProfile;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/PowerProfile( 4242): ambient.on is deprecated! Use ambient.on.display0 instead.
W/PowerProfile( 4242): screen.on is deprecated! Use screen.on.display0 instead.
W/PowerProfile( 4242): screen.full is deprecated! Use screen.full.display0 instead.
W/india.mobileap( 4242): Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/internal/os/PowerProfile;->getBatteryCapacity()D (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/DrmHal  ( 4242): found instance=clearkey version=android.hardware.drm@1.4::IDrmFactory
I/DrmHal  ( 4242): found instance=default version=android.hardware.drm@1.0::IDrmFactory
I/DrmHal  ( 4242): found instance=widevine version=android.hardware.drm@1.4::IDrmFactory
E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 4242): resolveInfoList is null or empty
E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 4242): PackagePriorityInfo list is null
E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 4242): <initHmsPackageInfoForMultiService> Failed to find HMS apk
I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 4242): Enter getHMSPackageNameForMultiService
E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 4242): resolveInfoList is null or empty
E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 4242): PackagePriorityInfo list is null
E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 4242): <initHmsPackageInfoForMultiService> Failed to find HMS apk
I/HMSSDK_HuaweiMobileServicesUtil( 4242): hmsPackageName is com.huawei.hwid
E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 4242): resolveInfoList is null or empty
E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 4242): PackagePriorityInfo list is null
E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 4242): <initHmsPackageInfoForMultiService> Failed to find HMS apk
I/HMSSDK_HuaweiMobileServicesUtil( 4242): HMS is not installed
I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 4242): enter asyncOnceCheckMDMState
I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager( 4242): quit asyncOnceCheckMDMState
W/System  ( 4242): A resource failed to call close. 
I/TestLibrary( 4242): Failed with error code 7
W/System  ( 4242): A resource failed to call close
```

Answer (score 1):

freeRASP author here. Your code seems to be alright. Described issues are common for apps accidentally built in debug mode. The protection generally becomes active in release mode. Which build mode did you use? The freeRASP documentation says that:

The Dev version is used during the development of the application. It separates development and production data and disables some checks which **won't** be triggered during the development process:

- Emulator-usage (onEmulatorDetected, onSimulatorDetected)
- Debugging (onDebuggerDetected)
- Signing (onTamperDetected, onSignatureDetected)

Which version of freeRASP is used is tied to the application's development stage - more precisely, how the application is compiled.

- debug (assembleDebug) = dev version
- release (assembleRelease) = release version

source: https://pub.dev/packages/freerasp#dev-vs-release-version